# Block ScrollView from becoming Responder React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I want to build a "Swipe to Delete" Component. It works fine if it's not inside a ScrollView. But when I put it inside a ScrollView and I try to swipe the component it starts scrolling the page (kinda not surprisingly). So to fix this I set up a state which controls `scrollEnabled` from the Scrollview and on the first touch on my component I set the state to `false`. And on release back to `true`.

But when I do this, because of the rerender, some of the first touches don't get recognized. So when a user swipes the component with a quick move and releases fairly quickly, it only recognizes the first touch. When I remove the `setScrollEnabled(false)` on the first touch it emits 3-5 more touch event for the same gesture.

So my question is whether it is possible to block ScrollView from scrolling without doing a full rerender or only having my component as the only responder to the touches and blocking all other. Or are there any other methods I could try. This is really frustrating.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { ScrollView, View } from "react-native";

export default function Test() {
  const [scrollEnabled, setScrollEnabled] = useState(true);

  const SwipeToDelete = () => {
    return (
      <View
        onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {
          setScrollEnabled(false);
          return true;
        }}
        onResponderMove={() => console.log("moving")}
        onResponderRelease={() => {
          setScrollEnabled(true);
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}>
      <SwipeToDelete />
      <SwipeToDelete />
      <SwipeToDelete />
      <SwipeToDelete />
      ...
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

This is what the code looks like currently. The Amin Problem ist that when I do a quick swipe move it only emits one single event. Without the `setState` I get 3-5 events. So my guess is that the rerender from the state setting blocks the events.

But I already found out in the docs for scrollview that there is currently no solution to this:

> Doesn't yet support other contained responders from blocking this
> scroll view from becoming the responder.